# Make changes in multiple files using sed and find

Tags: regex, bash, sed, find

I've got to go through 100+ sites and add two lines to the same file in all of them (sendmail1.php).
The boss wants me to hand copy/paste this stuff, but there's GOT to be an easier way, so I'm trying to do it with find and sed, both of which apparently I'm not using well. I just want to run a script in the dir housing the directories that have all of the sites in them.

I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Which file, sir? : " file

# find . -depth 1  -type f -name 'sendmail1.php' -exec \


sed -i 's/require\ dirname\(__FILE__\).\'\/includes\/validate.php\';/ \
        a require_once dirname\(__FILE__\).\'\/includes\/carriersoft_email.php\';' $file


sed -i 's/\else\ if\($_POST[\'email\']\ \&\&\ \($_POST\'work_email\'\]\ ==\ \"\"\)\){/ \
        a\t$carriersoft_sent = carriersoft_email\(\);' $file

exit 0
```

At the moment, I have the find commented out while trying to sort out sed here and testing the script, but I'd like to solve both.
I think I'm not escaping something necessary in the `sed` bits, but I keep going over it and changing it and getting different errors (sometimes "unfinished s/ statement" other times. other stuff.

The point is I have to do this:

Right below `require dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/validate.php';`, add this line:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/carriersoft_email.php';
```

AND

Under `else if($_POST['email'] && ($_POST['work_email'] == "")){`, add this line:

```
$carriersoft_sent = carriersoft_email();
```

I'd like to turn this 4 hours copy/pasta nightmare into a 2 minutes lazy admin type script it and get it done job.
But my fu is not strong with the sed or the find...
As for the find, I get "path must preceed expression: 1"
I've found questions here addressing that error, but indicating that using the '' to surround the filename should resolve it, but it's not working.

Comment: "(...) add two lines to the same file in all of them (...)" — then wouldn't it be easier to change just one file and copy it into all other locations?

Comment: There may be other site-specific differences in other parts of the file. I couldn't  get the boss to clarify this when I asked,"Why don't I just copy the edited file to all of those locations?" although I vimdiffed a few, and couldn't find any difference.

Comment: Ok. I DID just get a response from the boss:"I would prefer to edit each file, I am not sure about customizations we may have done for other specific sites."

Comment: Ok, but just for reference: checking if all such files are the same is easy — just choose one of them and compare it to all the others: `find . -name 'sendmail1.php' -exec diff -q path/to/reference/senmail1.php {} \;` (replace `path/to/reference/senmail1.php` with the chosen file). The `diff` command will output anything only if files differ. If they are the same as a single chosen file, they are all the same. :)

Comment: Thanks for that. That will definitely come in handy. These guys pay me by the hour, and budgeted 5 hours for this job, so I could just ride the clock on it, but I'd rather dazzle 'em with efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e "s/require dirname(__FILE__).'\/includes\/validate.php';/&\nrequire_once dirname(__FILE__).'\/includes\/carriersoft_email.php'\;/" \
-e "s/else if(\$_POST\['email'\] && (\$_POST\['work_email'\] == \"\")){/&\n\$carriersoft_sent = carriersoft_email();/"                   \
file
```

Note: I haven't used the `-i` flag. Once you are confirmed that it works for you, you can use the `-i` flag. Also I have combined your two `sed` command into one with `-e` option.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple and just use awk since awk can operate with strings, unlike sed which only works on REs with additional caveats:

```
find whatever |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    awk '
        { print }
        index($0,"require dirname(__FILE__).\047/includes/validate.php\047;") {
            print "require_once dirname(__FILE__).\047/includes/carriersoft_email.php\047;"
        }
        index($0,"else if($_POST[\047email\047] && ($_POST[\04work_email\047] == "")){") {
            print "$carriersoft_sent = carriersoft_email();"
        }
    ' "$file" > /usr/tmp/tmp_$$ &&
    mv /usr/tmp/tmp_$$ "$file"
done
```

With GNU awk you can use `-i inplace` to avoid manually specifying the tmp file name if you like, just like with `sed -i`.

The `\047`s are one way to specify a single quote inside a single-quote-delimited script.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be clearer if instead of `s` you used another fine command, `a`. To output one changed file, create a script (eg. `script.sed`) with the following content:

```
/require dirname(__FILE__)\.'\/includes\/validate.php';/a\
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/carriersoft_email.php';
/else if(\$_POST\['email'\] && (\$_POST\['work_email'\] == "")){/a\
$carriersoft_sent = carriersoft_email();
```

and run `sed -f script.sed sendmail1.php`.

To apply changes in all files, run:

```
find . -name 'sendmail1.php' -exec sed -i -f script.sed {} \;
```

(`-i` causes `sed` to change file in-place).

It is always advisable in such operations to do a backup and check out the exact changes after running the command. :)

Comment: Using `sed -i.bak …` automatically backs up the files.  Of course, the files should be under configuration management (version control) too, and backed up, so there shouldn't be any long-term risk, but it _is_ important to minimize the risk and possible time-out if the editing is being on the live systems.  And you need a reversion plan — being able to rename all the `.bak` files without their suffix helps with that.

Comment: Also, only the open square brackets have to be escaped in the second pattern.